# wrong parameter count error in mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this for far too long, and I don't see any error.

I've got a table that holds a bunch of locations. When I'm adding a location via my php script, I get an error of 'Wrong parameter count for mysql_query()'.

When I echo the mysql query, everything looks fine,and I can copy and and paste it into phpmyAdmin , everything runs perfectly.

The query looks like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (name, address, city, state, zip) VALUES ('Soboba Casino','23333 Soboba Road', 'San Jacinto', 'CA', '92581')
```

Am I missing something? Why would this not run in my script, but run in phpmyAdmin?

Sorry, Missed putting in the php, the offensive php seems pretty straight forward

```
// insert the venue
$insertLoc="INSERT IGNORE INTO locastions (loc, address, city, state, zip) VALUES ('$venueName','$streetAddress', '$city', '$state', '$zip')";
echo $insertLoc;
mysql_query($insertLoc)or die(mysql_query());
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet; I'll wager that isn't the exact query being passed into mysql_query().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the third line with

```
mysql_query($insertLoc)or die(mysql_error());
```

(Note that I've replaced the second `mysql_query()` with `mysql_error()`.)

Comment: of course! how could I be so stupid as to now notice that! Thank you Pourquoi.

Answer (score 1):

That's a PHP error, not a MySQL error.  Check your PHP code, and post it if you need more help.

Edited answer after question edit:
It's the die() clause.  `mysql_query` wants at least one parameter.  Someone else recommended using `mysql_error(),` which is probably what you meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

`or die(mysql_query());` should be `or die(mysql_error());`

Also, in your SQL I guess `locastions` should be `locations`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show the PHP causing this error?  If I were to guess I'd say it's a misplaced quote in the SQL you're creating, causing the parameter count to be off.

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (name, address, city, state, zip) VALUES ('$place", '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip')");
```

That would parse into multiple parameters.